# Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have jenkins running as docker container and i am installing docker from docker.com latest in global tool configuration.

in Jenkinsfile while initializing its working fine.

```
stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
                     env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${mavenHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

But in pipeline , its failing with below error.

```
ava.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    
    Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
```

Anything i am missing?

Comment: is the docker CLI command available in your Jenkins docker image?
are you sure you are referring to a correct docker home path by using tool DSL. Note If you are running Jenkins on a docker image make sure what ever tools path you used it has to be available with in Jenkins docker image or some how volume mapped, otherwise that tool will not be available

Comment: I would install docker on the host and start the container mapping the docker socket - this is a simple solution if you don't need to run multiple versions of docker. If you want to run DIND (docker in docker ) , you need to make sure the build user is in the docker group and the path variable is correctly defined.  I usually try to stay away from it if I don't need to test against multiple docker versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just add tools in your pipeline and install the docker plugines and docker pipeline plugin.

```
   pipeline {
      ...
      agent any
      //"docker" is from manageJenkins->Global tool configuration-> docker installation 
      //name.
      tools {dockerTool  "docker" } 
      stages {
        ...
      }
}
```